# porting encryption alghoritm using AesManaged and CryptoStream to windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

i'm porting a 5 years old wp7 app to wp 8.1, the follow code do not compile.
AesManaged and CryptoStream seems to be missing in 8.1 runtime.

is there some workaround?

```
public static string Encrypt(string Source,string CryptoKey)
{
  AesManaged aes = null;
  MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
  CryptoStream cryptoStream = null;
  //Generate a Key based on a Password, Salt and HMACSHA1 pseudo-random number generator 
  byte[] keyb = LoadKey(CryptoKey);
  aes = new AesManaged();
  aes.Key = keyb;
  aes.IV = keyb;
  //Create Memory and Crypto Streams 
  memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
  cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(),  CryptoStreamMode.Write);
  //Encrypt Data 
  byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Source);
  cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
  cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
  //Return Base 64 String 
  return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
  return Source;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no WinRT equivalent for these classes. Encryption code needs to be rewritten using the new libraries.

Here is the code snippet for AES

```
public string AES_Encrypt(string input, string pass)
{
SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider SAP = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesEcbPkcs7);
CryptographicKey AES;
HashAlgorithmProvider HAP = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Md5);
CryptographicHash Hash_AES = HAP.CreateHash();

string encrypted = "";
try
{
    byte[] hash = new byte[32];
    Hash_AES.Append(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass)));
    byte[] temp;
    CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(Hash_AES.GetValueAndReset(), out temp);

    Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16);
    Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16);

    AES = SAP.CreateSymmetricKey(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(hash));   

    IBuffer Buffer = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
    encrypted = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(AES, Buffer, null));

    return encrypted;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return null;
}
}


public string AES_Decrypt(string input, string pass)
{
SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider SAP = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesEcbPkcs7);
CryptographicKey AES;
HashAlgorithmProvider HAP = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Md5);
CryptographicHash Hash_AES = HAP.CreateHash();

string decrypted = "";
try
{
    byte[] hash = new byte[32];
    Hash_AES.Append(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass)));
    byte[] temp;
    CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(Hash_AES.GetValueAndReset(), out temp);

    Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16);
    Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16);

    AES = SAP.CreateSymmetricKey(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(hash));   

    IBuffer Buffer = CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String(input);
    byte[] Decrypted;
    CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(AES, Buffer, null), out Decrypted);
    decrypted = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Decrypted, 0, Decrypted.Length);

    return decrypted;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return null;
}
}
```

source: [How to do simple AES encryption/decryption in Metro?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/52080335-0016-4370-889b-3afe0c0dcb7a/how-to-do-simple-aes-encryptiondecryption-in-metro)